Question on Linux n_gsm 0710 driver issue during processing received data
When I try to build DLCI 1, it seems failed, here is log,
//open DLCI 0,
gsm_send_packet: 00000000: f9 03 3f 01 1c f9  
gsmld_receive_buf: 00000000: f9 03 73 01 d7 f9 

//open DLCI 1,
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 I gsm_send_packet: 00000000: f9 07 3f 01 de f9                            
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 I gsmld_output: 00000000: f9 07 3f 01 de f9                               
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 E         : gsm_data_kick list_empty! return!
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 E         : gsmld_write_task
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 E         : gsm_data_kick ttyflag=2048

//trigger a SABM at the same time(Can this be removed? or is it mandatory?)
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 I gsm_send_packet: 00000000: f9 03 ef 09 e3 05 07 8d fb f9                
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 I gsmld_output: 00000000: f9 03 ef 09 e3 05 07 8d fb f9                   
07-10  15:31:34.399   950   950 E         : gsm_data_kick list_empty! return!

//UA from host B for both frames sent above returned （26 octets in total）
07-10  15:31:34.407   249   249 I gsmld_receive_buf: 00000000: f9 07 73 01 15 f9 f9 01 ff 09 e3 05 07 8d 8f f9  
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 I gsmld_receive_buf: 00000010: f9 03 ff 09 e1 05 07 8d ee f9                    
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsmld_receive_buf --flag 0 count=26
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->state=0
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->fcs=255
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsmld_receive_buf --flag 0 count=25
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->state=2
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->fcs=186
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsmld_receive_buf --flag 0 count=24
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->state=3
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->fcs=15
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsmld_receive_buf --flag 0 count=23
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->state=8
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->fcs=234
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsmld_receive_buf --flag 0 count=22
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->state=6
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->fcs=207
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsmld_receive_buf --flag 0 count=21
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm0_receive  gsm->state=10
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm_queue addr=3, gsm->fcs=207
07-10  15:31:34.408   249   249 E         : gsm_dlci_open state=2

//here procedure stop processing received buffer data, around 1s unreasonablely
//then, T2 timeout, and gsm_control_retransmit is called.
07-10  15:31:35.434     0     0 E         : [    C2] gsm_control_retransmit ctrl=759782080
07-10  15:31:35.434   950   950 E         : gsmld_write_task
07-10  15:31:35.434   950   950 E         : gsm_data_kick ttyflag=2048
07-10  15:31:35.434   950   950 I gsm_send_packet: 00000000: f9 03 ef 09 e3 05 07 8d fb f9 

Does anybody know why 'gsmld_receive_buf' stop processing received buffer data at octets 21?
here is source code same as,
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/n_gsm.c
static void gsmld_receive_buf(struct tty_struct *tty, const u8 *cp,
                  const u8 *fp, size_t count)
{
    struct gsm_mux *gsm = tty->disc_data;
    u8 flags = TTY_NORMAL;

    if (debug & DBG_DATA)
        gsm_hex_dump_bytes(__func__, cp, count);

    for (; count; count--, cp++) {
        if (fp)
            flags = *fp++;
        switch (flags) {
        case TTY_NORMAL:
            if (gsm->receive)
                gsm->receive(gsm, *cp);
            break;
        case TTY_OVERRUN:
        case TTY_BREAK:
        case TTY_PARITY:
        case TTY_FRAME:
            gsm_error(gsm);
            break;
        default:
            WARN_ONCE(1, "%s: unknown flag %d\n",
                   tty_name(tty), flags);
            break;
        }
    }
    /* FASYNC if needed ? */
    /* If clogged call tty_throttle(tty); */
}





After I posted this question, my rights for posting question is blocked, does admin know why? thanks. @admin
